# Get the list of installed packages with install time, date and vendor details with dpkg-query command

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I am trying to get package name with version, splitted package and version, vendor of that package, install time and date using:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}-${version} ${package} ${version} ${Maintainer} ${installtime}\n'
```

But I got package name with version, splitted package and version, vendor of that package. I was not able to retrieve install time and date.

How can I get package install time and date with the above query?

Comment: [Related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/list-packages-by-installation-date)

Comment: I write a [lsmipkgs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716735/529615) command to do that.

Answer (score 7):

`dpkg-query` does not have any field option to show date/time of installation. The other way of saying this is that `dpkg` does not store this information. Under the hood, `dpkg-query` uses various files in `/var/lib/dpkg/` to get the information.

Here are the available field names:

```
Architecture
Bugs
Conffiles (internal)
Config-Version (internal)
Conflicts
Breaks
Depends
Description
Enhances
Essential
Filename (internal, front-end related)
Homepage
Installed-Size
MD5sum (internal, front-end related)
MSDOS-Filename (internal, front-end related)
Maintainer
Origin
Package
Pre-Depends
Priority
Provides
Recommends
Replaces
Revision (obsolete)
Section
Size (internal, front-end related)
Source
Status (internal)
Suggests
Tag (usually not in .deb but in repository Packages files)
Triggers-Awaited (internal)
Triggers-Pending (internal)
Version
```

And some virtual fields too:

```
binary:Package
binary:Summary
db:Status-Abbrev
source:Package
source:Version
```

Check `man dpkg-query` to get a broader idea.

---

Note that, you can look at `/var/log/dpkg.log*` for the installation date/time of packages. Also note that, if your package is installed by `apt-get` (or brothers), you can look at the `apt` history files, `/var/log/apt/history.log*`, too.

Comment: ok.. I tried to use below command.  locate dpkg.log | xargs cat {} | grep "install"  | awk '{print $5$6, $5,$6,$2,$1}'. Here i got package name with version, splitted package, version, Install time and date. Not able to get vendor details. Could you please let me know how i will get vendor details with the command.

Comment: @KISHORE what do you mean by vendor details?

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```bash
sudo dpkg-query -f '${binary:Package}\n' -W > packages_list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, but i think it is too slow.

```sh
function lspkgs {
    local installation_text=$(grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log*)
    for i in $(dpkg-query -f='${Package}\n' -W); do
        echo $(dpkg-query -f='${Package}-${version} ${package} ${version} ${Maintainer} ${installtime}\n' -W $i) $(echo "$installation_text" | grep " install $i:" | sort -n | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f 1,2)
    done
}
```

The output of `lspkgs` command.

```
adduser-3.118 adduser 3.118 Debian Adduser Developers <adduser@packages.debian.org> 2022-09-09 03:16:59
alsa-topology-conf-1.2.4-1 alsa-topology-conf 1.2.4-1 Debian ALSA Maintainers <pkg-alsa-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org> 2022-09-09 11:46:40
alsa-ucm-conf-1.2.4-2 alsa-ucm-conf 1.2.4-2 Debian ALSA Maintainers <pkg-alsa-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org> 2022-09-09 11:46:42
anacron-2.3-30 anacron 2.3-30 Debian QA Group <packages@qa.debian.org> 2022-09-09 11:46:44
```

Comment: What about when that image is gone?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Is the image `/var/log/dpkg.log*`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also run below command as show in Screenshot reference.

```
ls -ltr /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
```

[image]